# Variável nunca chega a zero utilizando randi

Tags: algoritmo, visualg

Teria como eu mostrar **Vida: 0** no resultado do console do VisuAlg?

Eu tentei colocar **Ate(life = 0)** mas dá loop infinito.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, eu agradeço.

A versão do meu VisuAlg é o 2.0

```
algoritmo "RPG"
var
   damage, life: Inteiro
inicio
   life <- 100
   EscrevaL("Vida: ", life)
   Repita
       EscrevaL(" >>> Dano causado: ", damage)
       EscrevaL("Vida: ", life)
       damage <- randi(life)
       life <- life - damage
   Ate(life = 1)
   Se (life = 1) entao
       EscrevaL("Inimigo abatido!")
   FimSe
fimalgoritmo
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente com `life <= 0`. Por quê `damage` recebe `randi(life)`?

Comment: `Ate(life <= 0)` entrou em loop também.
`damage` recebe `randi(life)` para poder gerar um número aleatório a partir do `100` por que `life <- 100`. O `randi` é uma função de randomização.

Comment: Tem como por o exemplo da saída quando entra em loop? Aliás, `randi(life)` pode retornar `life` ou é de 0 a `life-1`?

Comment: Substitui `damage <- randi(life)` por `damage <- randi(80)`. Agora parou de dar loop mesmo com `Ate(life <= 0)`. Parece que agora está funcionando. [Clique aqui para ver a imagem](https://i.imgur.com/T5OmEI1.jpg)

Comment: É, então pode usar `life = 0` e colocar `randi(life+1)`

Comment: Apenas como aparte, se está numa linguagem em que as palavras reservadas são em português, porque não utilizar nomes de variáveis também em português ?

Comment: `randi(life+1)` também funcionou, acho que resolve melhor do que a minha gambiarra de colocar `randi(80)`. Obrigado.

Comment: É por que a life tava chegando a `0` e o `randi` estava tentando randomizar o `0`, por isso estava dando loop.

Comment: Verdade @Isac, eu poderia ter seguido o português, mas era apenas para teste, obrigado por me ajudarem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `randi(x)` retorna um número aleatório no conjunto `[0, x[`, ou seja, um número entre `0` e `x-1`. Desta forma, chegará um momento que restará apenas 1 de vida (`life = 1`) e fazendo `randi(life)` sempre retornará 0. Se sempre retorna zero, a vida nunca ficará abaixo de 1, entrando em um *loop* infinito - e isso explica porquê quando você fez a condição `life = 1` o programa encerrou.

Para resolver, basta fazer `randi(life+1)`, para que seja sorteado um valor do conjunto `[0, life+1[`, ou `[0, life]`, e, assim, a vida chegará em algum momento a zero, podendo manter a condição `life = 0`:

```
algoritmo "RPG"
var
   dano, vida: Inteiro
inicio
   life <- 100
   EscrevaL("Vida: ", vida)
   Repita
       dano <- randi(vida+1)
       vida <- vida - dano
       EscrevaL(" >>> Dano causado: ", dano)
       EscrevaL("Vida: ", vida)
   Ate(vida = 0)
   EscrevaL("Inimigo abatido!")
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.